# Extracting values from inside polygons raster r

Tags: r, raster, r-sp, rgdal

I'm trying to find the mean daily temperature for counties in South Dakota from raster grids ('bil' files) found at http://prism.oregonstate.edu/.  I am getting county boundaries from the 'maps' package.

```
library(maps)
library(raster)
sd_counties <- map('county','south dakota')
sd_raster <- raster('file_path')
```

How do I extract the grid cells within each county?  I think I need to turn each county into it's own polygon to do this, but how?  Then, I should be able to do something like the following.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
values <- extract(raster, list of polygons)  
polygon_means <- unlist(lapply(values, FUN=mean))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `maps` package or the `map` function, but it looks like it's solely for visualization, rather than geospatial operations.

While there might be a way to convert the `map` object to actual polygons, here's an easy way sing `raster`'s `getData` function that works:

```
library(raster)

usa_adm2 <- getData(country='USA',level=2)

sd_counties <- usa_adm2[grepl('South Dakota',usa_adm2$NAME_1),]

plot(sd_counties)
```

[image]

Now you can extract pixels for each county using `extract(r,sd_counties)`, where `r` is your desired raster.

Note, that depending on the number of pixels (and layers) you need to extract, that can take some time.

Comment: Do you know if this is the fastest method?  This is going to take a very long time if so.

Comment: Have a look at the `velox` package. I don't have any personal experience with it, but looks promising. Another option is to rasterize your polygons and extract your values with indexing.

Comment: The velox package speeds up extraction probably by 5 times or so, very nice!