# how to efficiently extract values from (many) large raster(s) for many polygones

Tags: r, spatial, r-raster, r-sf

I have a set of points and **I want to extract values from several large rasters** for a buffer around those points. *The rasters are too large to be held in memory* (> 1e10 cells). I illustrate my current approach below but would be interested if there is a faster approach.

```
library(maps)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(parallel)

# sf object with polygones for which we want values
crs <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
map <- sf::st_as_sf( maps::map(regions = "Sweden", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
map <- st_transform(map, crs = crs)
sf_points <- st_sfc(st_sample(map, 100))

sf_points <- 
  data.frame(A = 1:length(sf_points)) %>% 
  st_set_geometry(sf_points) 

# raster too large to fit in memory
# the raster(s) I am working on has 10m resolution

r <- raster(extent(map), nrow = 15000, ncol = 7000,
       crs = crs)

values(r) <- rep(sample(1:10, 77, replace = T),  length.out = ncell(r))

#use the parallel package for parallel processing
cluster <- makeCluster(4)
clusterExport(cluster, c("r","sf_points", "as_Spatial"))

List_points <- 
  sf_points %>% 
  mutate(split = rep(1:ceiling(n()/4), each=4, length.out=n())) %>% # 4 cores
  split(f = .$split) %>% 
  parLapply(cl = cluster, X = ., function(x) raster::extract(r, y = as_Spatial(x), buffer = 5000)) %>% 
  unlist(recursive = F)
```

I repeat the extraction for each raster. As the values are ordered I can then summarize the pixel values across lists. I cannot (easily) create a raster stack as the raster have different extent.

using the `velox` package has sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565713/extracting-values-from-inside-polygons-raster-r) doesn't seem to work as it tries to load the raster into memory which fails. I could try to load it chunk-wise but then I would need to figure out which points are on which chunk...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can speed this up a bit using polygons without aggregating (dissolving) the buffers

```
library(raster)
swe <- getData("GADM", country="SWE", level=0)
set.seed(0)
pts <- spsample(swe, 100, "regular")
r <- raster(swe, nrow = 15000, ncol=7000)
values(r) <- rep(sample(1:10, 77, replace = T),  length.out = ncell(r))

b1 <- buffer(pts, 5000, dissolve=FALSE)
b2 <- buffer(pts, 5000, dissolve=TRUE)

system.time(e1 <- extract(r, pts, buffer=5000))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.39    0.02    1.40 
system.time(e2 <- extract(r, b1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.88    0.00    0.88 
system.time(e3 <- extract(r, b2))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  26.34   25.02   51.52
```

Clearly `b1` performs much better than `b2`; but not that much faster than the first approach.

You say you cannot make a RasterStack because the rasters have different extents. If (and only if!), however, they have the same origin and resolution, you could first translate all areas to xy coordinates and then use these.

Something like this:

```
z <- rasterize(b, r)
pts <- rasterToPoints(z, xy=TRUE)
```

The above takes time, but after that

```
system.time(a <- extract(r, zz[,1:2]))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.04
```

It could be faster to do this is parallel for each point, and use `crop(raster(r), polygon)` before rasterize.

Comment: I am not sure why but calculating the buffer outside raster::extract is much slower for me. Replacing the function in parLapply with ```function(x) {
    y = as_Spatial(x)
    y = raster::buffer(y, 500, dissolve = FALSE)
    raster::extract(r,y)
     }```  increases the time from ```user: 0.13 system:0.016 elapsed: 3.29``` to ```user 0.132  system 0.04 elapsed 19.652```. Actually using ```dissolve = TRUE``` *speeds things up*  (user 0.112  system 0.022 elapsed 8.13) but is still much slower than the first approach.  *note that the times above is for an extract of my real data

Comment: I added another idea

Comment: I accept this answer as it lead me to the right solution. My real data have several points clustered in groups of 8. I now first generate a polygon large enough to encompass the group of points + the buffer, then I crop the raster *for each polygon* getting a list of raster. Then I use ```extract()``` in ```future::future_lapply()``` extracting the data for the buffer around each point, matching it with the cropped raster. I repeat this for each raster. In my real example this cuts the time from 30 min (or more) per raster down to ~2 min (and it scales well with number of points).

Comment: I think this works because cropping a (small) polygon from a large raster is fast and extracting data from a polygon on a small raster is also fast. Rasterizing all polygons is slow (to impossible in memory) and extracting from a large raster is also slow. Using ```rasterToPoints```does speed things up (factor of 2) but even extracting through indexing is slow for large raster.